# NullPointerException for JComboBox.requestFocus

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I am trying to focus jComboBox2 from RPSearchToolView.class as my program launches the mainframe. However `NullPointerException` was returned to my console. Can someone help me figure out whats wrong with my code. I put requestfocus inside the main as shown below.

```
/**
 * Main method launching the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(RPSearchToolApp.class, args);                
    RPSearchToolView.jComboBox2.requestFocus(true);         
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at rpsearchtool.RPSearchToolApp.main(RPSearchToolApp.java:222)
```

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: You do not provide enough information or enough code for anyone to provide useful help. The best we can tell you right now is that on line 222 of class rpsearchtool.RPSearchToolApp, in your main method, one of the objects you are using is null.

Comment: @user1157559 : Moreover instead of using RPSearchToolView.jComboBox2.requestFocus(true);, you should be using RPSearchToolView.jComboBox2.requestFocusInWindow();. That is much better way.  Regards

Comment: @blackpanda i realized that accessing jComboBox immediately after the launch method will definitely throw nullpointerexception, because it take a while before all the components in application to initialize/to be realize. Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @GagandeepBali thanks i tried requestFocusInWindow, and its far better than requestFocus. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked whether jComboBox2 is null?  If you don't use a debugger (which I strongly recommend), then put a statement after 'launch' and test "(jComboBox2 == null)".

It is also possible that requesting focus before the component is realized causes a null pointer exception; I haven't tried that.  But it wouldn't surprise me at all that requesting focus before realization is illegal.  You can realize by showing the component(s), or calling pack() on the frame they're in.

Comment: _Thanks, it works. I tried to put Thread.sleep(1000) after the launch method, since all components were realized already, calling jComboBox is now possible. Thank you very much._